# Codeception with CakePHP gives PHPUnit array to string conversion error

Tags: cakephp, codeception

I’m using Codeception with CakePHP 3.5, and has written a few testing steps. But when executing them, it gives me an error when there should be no error as far as I can see. The first few steps works fine, but when I get to the step to click on a button, I get the error “PHPUnit framework exception: array to string conversion”.

I’m using the codeception code:
$I->click([‘button’ => [‘title’ => ‘Delete testtest, tt’]]);

Trying to click on the element:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs delete-namestring" title="Delete testtest, tt" id="20867"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</button>
```

Clicking on it manually works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because you have an array as the value of the `button`.

Try one of these:

```
$I->click(['css' => 'button.delete-namestring']);

$I->click('button.delete-namestring');

$I->click('class', 'delete-namestring');
```